# why `semantic error TS2344: Type '"ptn3"' does not satisfy the constraint '"ptn1" | "ptn2"'.`

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 3.8.3.
I wanted to specify the interface key and get the type information, so I wrote the following code.

```
interface T1 {
  ptn1 : string
  ptn2 : number
}

type Factory<N extends keyof T1, T extends T1 = T1> = T1[N]

type F1 = Factory<'ptn1'> // F1 type is "string"
```

ok, it works.
And then, I wanted to extend the `T1` type to be able to use it, so I changed it as follows.

```
export interface T1 {
  ptn1 : string
  ptn2 : number
}

export type Factory<N extends keyof T1, T extends T1 = T1> = T1[N]

// OTHER FILE --------------

import { T1, Factory } from './above_code.ts'

type F1 = Factory<'ptn1'> // F1 type is "string"

interface T2 extends T1 {
  ptn3: Object
}
type T2keys = keyof T2 // T2keys = "ptn3" | "ptn1" | "ptn2"

type F2 = Factory<'ptn2'> // F2 type is "number"
```

But the following code will output an error.

```
// A continuation of the code above..
type F3 = Factory<'ptn3', T2> // semantic error TS2344: Type '"ptn3"' does not satisfy the constraint '"ptn1" | "ptn2"'.
```

Why TS2344 error?
How can I write that `type 3 = Factory<'ptn3', T2>` become an `Object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually use `T` inside the `Factory` type:

```
export type Factory<N extends keyof T, T extends T1 = T1> = T[N]



export interface T1 {
  ptn1 : string
  ptn2 : number
}

type F1 = Factory<'ptn1'> // F1 type is "string"

interface T2 extends T1 {
  ptn3: Object
}
type F2 = Factory<'ptn2'> // F2 type is "number"

type F3 = Factory<'ptn3', T2>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=30&pln=4&pc=1#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACRBPa5kDECGBjRBNAHgDlkpFwA7AEwGdkBrcNWAM2QBUAaHypGr0m3AIzIAvDzEA+KTwDaZALqh1IKHCTIAljWrwOBLOOQBvUMmTRENCQC5kDRPH0BzKzbsAmZE5oAVwBbACNweFAAXw10TBwJaTxCYhIAclt7NPkAehyE1AwsXSYAIhc3GndSjX1DY3xTPypaRhkLL0yAZicAeVCAK3BCaNA4rGw-JIIieFIM32zkPJw-cb0yoLCImrAQdewuhWTZ+e60-m4fWSA)